# My Game is crashing on Android 8.1 , using unity 5.6.2 report that i receive on googleplay console ia am sharing below

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

My Game is crashing on  Android 8.1 , using unity 5.6.2 report that i receive on googleplay console ia am sharing below

**Lava Z50 (Z50), Android 8.1 - Report 1 of 4**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider (ActivityThread.java:6291)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders (ActivityThread.java:5854)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:5771)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1 (Unknown Source
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1680)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6545)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:857)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider (ActivityThread.java:6276)
```

Comment: This is Java not C#.... get your tags right.

Comment: @S.Fragkos : It seems like it's Unity3D. C# tags is perhaps not bad in this case. But we doens't have enough information to help ali. Ali: Can you share the code who throw this exception on your code ? Thanks a lot